# Using the gem globalize, how to switch locales for input only and not the whole page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, globalize

**Context:** For a Ruby on Rails app for bike rentals, I am using the gem globalize to deal with input `:description` in different languages.

**Curent state:** The globalize implementation worked, depending on my locale I am able to store `description` in a specific language. The input for `:description` is dealt with on the basis of the locale of an entire webpage.

This means that everything on this page has to change in language in order to store `:description` in the correct language.

Alternatively, I am also able to show all available locales and show `description` for each of them. (See also the commented out code below).

**Question:** I'm searching for a way to let the user select a language for `:description` only and then save `:description` in the correct language without changing the language of the entire webpage.

**Code**

form

```
<div class="row">
        <%# I18n.available_locales.each do |locale| %>
          <!-- <h1><%#= locale %></h1> -->
          <%= f.globalize_fields_for locale do |ff| %>
          <div class="col-10">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="form-control-label text required" for="accommodation_category_description">Description</label>
              <div><%= ff.text_area :description, :rows =>"5", :cols =>"30",  class:"form-control is-valid text required" %></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <%# end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

initializers/globalization.rb

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class FormBuilder
      #
      # Helper that renders translations fields
      # on a per-locale basis, so you can use them separately
      # in the same form and still saving them all at once
      # in the same request.

      def globalize_fields_for(locale, *args, &proc)
        raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
        @index = @index ? @index + 1 : 1
        object_name = "#{@object_name}[translations_attributes][#{@index}]"
        object = @object.translations.find_by_locale locale.to_s
        @template.concat @template.hidden_field_tag("#{object_name}[id]", object ? object.id : "")
        @template.concat @template.hidden_field_tag("#{object_name}[locale]", locale)
        @template.fields_for(object_name, object, *args, &proc)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Globalize.with_locale` to temporarily set locale, this works for views too:

```
<% Globalize.with_locale(some_other_locale) do %>
  in this part of the page locale will be <%= locale.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

But for your case more user-friendly way would be to make the form dynamic, so that user can add translation for several languages of their liking.

Globalize translations are just an additional table/model `YourModel::Translation` with fields for locale and translated fields, so you can work directly with these as with any other nested forms.

Add [gem cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to your project, that will handle dynamic forms (if you're using webpacker instead of asset pipeline - that may require additional steps, to add global jquery and require js from gem using erb interpolation, [see more here](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/452#issuecomment-384836675)).

In your model:

```rb
translates :description #, ...
accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations, allow_destroy: true
```

in controller:

```rb
def your_some_params
  params.require(:your_model_name).permit(
        ...
        translations_attributes: [
          :id, :_destroy,
          :locale,
          :description,
        ]
      )
end
```

in form:

```
  <div id='translations'>
    <%= form.fields_for :translations do |t| %>
      <%= render 'translation_fields', f: t %>
    <% end %>

    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add translation', form, :translations  %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

partial for translations like:

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <%= f.hidden_field  :id %>
  <%= f.select :locale, I18n.available_locales %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove this translation", f %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Vasfed!! Really usefull